# ffmpeg, apply fade only to video input using filter_complex while concating

Tags: ffmpeg, video-processing

```
ffmpeg -i foo.mp4 -filter_complex "fade=d=0.5, reverse, fade=d=0.5, reverse" output.mp4
```

can be used to fade in and out foo.mp4 video. (we do not care about audio). According to https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/19867/how-to-fade-in-out-a-video-audio-clip-with-unknown-duration

It's good but only works in the simple situation of 1 input video, and 1 output. Now, how can I apply the fade in and out effect in the following more complex situation? I'm trying to concat `a.jpg` (a picture) with `bar.mp4`. I want only the bar.mp4 portion to fade in and out.

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -t 2 -framerate 1 -i a.jpg  -f lavfi -t 2 -i anullsrc -r 24 -i bar.mp4 -filter_complex "[0][1][2:v][2:a] concat=n=2:v=1:a=1 [vpre][a];[vpre]fps=24[v]" -map "[v]" -map "[a]" out.mp4 -y
```

Of course, I could first create a temporary `temp.mp4` from bar.mp4 by running the first command, then input `temp.mp4` in my second command. This involves an extra step and extra encoding. Could anyone help fix the commands or suggest something even better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

`ffmpeg -loop 1 -t 2 -framerate 24 -i a.jpg -f lavfi -t 2 -i anullsrc -r 24 -i bar.mp4 -filter_complex "[2:v]fade=d=0.5, reverse, fade=d=0.5, reverse[v2];[0][1][v2][2:a] concat=n=2:v=1:a=1 [v][a]" -map "[v]" -map "[a]" out.mp4 -y`

Comment: Thanks! `[2:v]fade=d=0.5, reverse, fade=d=0.5, reverse[v2]` means `take video stream of input index 2, apply fade filter, and name the product as v2`, correct? ffmpeg syntax is hard to master, do you recommend good resources (other than official doc)? @Gyan